# QGIS - create new feature layer with total counts after join

Tags: qgis, shapefile, spatial-join, vector-layer

I have a dataset with counts (coutns). These are spatially joined to polygons with 'fid' (column 3). As you see in the attached image, id '1' with counts '5' belongs to fid '330832'/ id '2' and '3' both have different counts, and belong to the same fid '335068'.

[image: Example header]

How can I create a new layer, in which the counts are summed per fid? i.e. the new table would look like this:

[image]

Hope my question is clear.

Best, Paolo

Answer (score 2):

`sum("coutns",group_by:="fid")` does what you're looking for.

[`sum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=sum#sum) returns the added up values of a column or expression. The additional `group_by:=` modifies the expression so that the sum is created for each group/categorie/different value in the specified column.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast reply! That is exactly what I needed.

Comment: As a new user, please be adviced that this side tries to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235